# Only allow numeric values in the textbox

Tags: vb6, textbox, numbers

I want to make a TextBox control that only accepts numerical values.

How can I do this in VB6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the text box text `Change` event, check if the entered value is a number. If it's not a number then set the old value back again.

```
Dim textval As String
Dim numval As String

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  textval = TextBox1.Text
  If IsNumeric(textval) Then
    numval = textval
  Else
    TextBox1.Text = CStr(numval)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You rather use Validate event.

Comment: It depends. You should use the `Validate` event if you want the verification that only numbers have been entered to be triggered when the user leaves the textbox control and tries to set focus to something else. If you go that route, then and only then will an error or notification be presented. On the other hand, if you use the `Change` event, the user will be notified immediately that a non-numeric value they typed in is invalid.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on control box > component > Control -> Microsoft Masked Edit Control 6.0.
Or with normal textbox:

```
Private Sub Text1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
 Cancel = Not IsNumeric(Text1.Text)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

i usually use this code:

```
Private Sub text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If Not IsNumeric(text1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I let the API do it for me. I add this function to a .bas module and call it for any edit control that I need to set to numeric only.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ES_NUMBER = &H2000&
Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long


'set an editbox to numeric only - return the previous
'style on success or zero on error
Public Function ForceNumeric(ByVal EditControlhWnd As Long) As Long
    Dim lngCurStyle As Long
    Dim lngReturn As Long

    lngCurStyle = GetWindowLong(EditControlhWnd, GWL_STYLE)
    If lngCurStyle <> 0 Then
        lngReturn = SetWindowLong(EditControlhWnd, GWL_STYLE, lngCurStyle Or ES_NUMBER)
    End If

    ForceNumeric = lngReturn

End Function
```

To use it call the function with the handle of the TextBox.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim lngResult As Long

    lngResult = ForceNumeric(Text1.hwnd)

End Sub
```

Comment: This has its issues, though. You can copy any nonnumeric text and paste it into the control via (1) Ctrl-V, (2) Shift-Insert, and (3) the text box' context menu. Only (1) can be addressed in VB6 via KeyPress.

Comment: @Herb, You're correct, but the only way to prevent pasting invalid values into a textbox in VB is to capture the system messages. It is possible, but an ugly thing to do in VB6. This only prevents typing in a non-numeric value. If I need to insure my data integrity I check the text is valid before I use it for processing. In the meantime I have made it more difficult for the user to enter invalid data. In .Net I combine this with monitoring the message stream for WM_PASTE (I think) and inspect the information to be pasted before allowing it.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this code:

```
Private Sub text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=350067

You need to check each keypress, or you can do one validation at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be used for whole numbers:

```
Private Sub text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If Not IsNumeric(text1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then    KeyAscii = 0
    if (KeyAscii>=43) and (KeyAscii<=46) Then KeyAscii = 0 
    'it ignores '-', '+', '.' and ','
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in my project:

```
Private Sub txtReceiptID_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim Keychar As String
If KeyAscii > 31 Then
    Keychar = Chr(KeyAscii)
    If Not IsNumeric(Keychar) Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    textval = Text1.Text
    If IsNumeric(textval) Then
        numval = textval
    Else
        Text1.Text = CStr(numval)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Just select the control and the keyPress method and the IDE create the next method for you. Then add the next code inside the method

```
Private Sub txtControl_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   KeyAscii = RealKeyascii(txtControl, KeyAscii, 256 ^ 8)
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation to your coce-only answer? It would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

**Just write simple 1 line
In text change
Text1.text1=val(text1.text)**

Answer (score -1):

```
If Len(Text2.Text) > 0 Then
    If IsNumeric(Text2.Text) = False Then
        Text2.SetFocus
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS CODE: DISABLES LETTER(A-Z,a-z) AND ACCEPTS BACKSPACE, DOTS, COMMAS AND NUMBERS(0-9) =)

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If Not (KeyAscii >= vbKeyA And KeyAscii <= vbKeyZ) And Not (KeyAscii >= 97 And KeyAscii <= 122) Then
Else
KeyAscii = 0
End If
End Sub

Comment: The question was answered 8 years ago and your code has no formatting making it difficult to read. Please try to answer new unanswered questions vs old questions that have already had accepted answers.