# How can I check the time format entered in a textbox?

Tags: vb6, time, textbox

I'm using VB 6, and my form has a `TextBox` control. I want the user to be able to enter the time in the textbox, but I have to validate whether the input time is correct or not.

Example:

```
Textbox1.Text = 236161  '(User Input)

236161 = HHMMSS
```

The above entered time is wrong because the minutes and seconds are greater than 60.

What code can I use to check the format of the time entered in the textbox?

Comment: This is similar with your question about number:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506105/only-numeric-values-in-the-textbox/4506169#4506169. Let gather all-into-one.Pls.

Comment: there must be separation in hh,mm and sec. otherwise how will you differentiate weather 111 is 11=hh, 1=mm or 1=sec or 11=hh and 1 =min.

Comment: @pinichi: I disagree. The similiarity is only superficial. This question is specifically about time, while the other is about only allowing numeric values. Here, there needs to be validation logic (as mentioned in the question) to determine if the hours, minutes, and seconds fall into the appropriate ranges. The `IsNumeric` function suggested in the answers to the other question is not sufficient.

Comment: Then a  `IsTime()` or a maskedit will work, Just an advise that he should solve similar problems by himself. What if he need an text box that only accept date, telephone number?

Comment: @pinichi: My version of VB 6 doesn't have an `IsTime()` function. Does yours? I don't think that will work. And while I agree with you to a certain extent that there are merits to learning how to solve problems yourself, that hardly seems consistent with the point of a Q&A site like this one.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Then isDate("1/1/1900 "+"time") or event can create IsTime() by some codeline or whatever. I also suggested the maskedit, can be use more widely in other cases. If he try to use, he can save the time by another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest that you use a `DTPicker` control, instead.** This is the date/time picker that is available for VB 6 applications, and it essentially forces the user (but much more gently than that makes it sound) to enter a valid time in the proper format. Trying to do this validation yourself is a giant pain in the rear, and not worth the effort since using a built-in control makes it so much simpler.

You can start using this in your project by following these steps:

1. In the VB 6 IDE, open the "Project" menu, and then click "Components" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Scroll down nearly to the bottom of the list and select "Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2" (preferably version 6.0, if available, rather than version 5.0).
3. Once you click OK, you will find a handful of new controls added to your toolbox. Find and click on the one called `DTPicker`. It will look something like this:

   [image: DTPicker control in VB 6 toolbox]
4. Drag the `DTPicker` control to your form.
5. Make sure that the control you just added is selected, then in the "Properties" window, scroll down to the "Format" property and set it to "2 - dtpTime". This specifies that you want to accept a time value in the `DTPicker` control, rather than a date.

Comment: In a Datetimepicker i set a time only, it is diplaying 12 Hours Format (HH:MM:SS AM or PM),  I need 24 Hours Format

Comment: @Gopal: If you want to use a 24-hour format, you have to specify a custom format. Set the "Format" property to "3 - dtpCustom" instead, and then enter "HH:mm:ss" for the "CustomFormat" property ("hh" indicates two digit hours for the 12-hour format, while "HH" represents two digit hours for the 24-hour format).

Comment: Downvoter: care to leave a comment why you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: How can I make it more than 24 hours?, that is, I want to enter if possible 1000 hours or more.

Answer (score 0):

With .Net you have regex included.  With VB 6 you have to use COM or ActiveX libraries and add them as references to your project (http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802)

For samples of regex to check time see: http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the format function like this:

```
TestStr = Format(TestDateTime, "HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks zedo, But how to write this code, For Example Textbox1.text = 236161, how your code will work here, can you give more ideas