# Is it possible to prohibit pasting the clipboard's textual content into a TextBox control?

Tags: winapi, vb6

If the user tries to paste copied text via Ctrl-V, I can invoke KeyPress:

```
Private Sub cTextBox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 22 Then               '22 is Ctrl-V.
        Beep
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

But what do I do when she uses the (admittedly less common) Shift-Insert combination? KeyPress won't receive this key. KeyDown and KeyUp don't let us cancel the input.

Is sub-classing the only possibility?

And what about the option 'Paste' in the popup menu? Can I get rid of it by setting a windows style in SetWindowLong? Which?

Comment: Why do you want to make the life of your users harder than it already is? I hope you don't do this for "security" reasons...

Comment: @DirkVollmar, my reason is robustness. My TextBox accepts digits only. I'm enforcing this with the ES_NUMBER style of SetWindowLong. But it is possible to paste any text into it, whole books if you will. The code shown is over-simplified to demonstrate how I can catch the paste intention. In reality, I examine the Clipboard object and let nonnegative integers pass through. In the other cases a Beep and a KeyAscii = 0 provides the same eperience as the attempt to enter a non digit.

Comment: Wouldn't [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4506145/40347) be a much better and more rubust way?

Comment: Ugh... if *"robustness"* is your goal, don't implement a brittle kludge. Instead, handle the [EN_CHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676.aspx) notification, and disable the *Submit*/*Ok*/*whatever* button, if there are invalid entries anywhere.

Comment: It does not quite provide the same experience; Common Controls version 6's `EDIT` control also throws up a (possibly localized) balloon tip. And how do you deal with mixed numeric and textual input? Also IIRC didn't Common Controls version 6 fix this issue?

Comment: Subclass and intercept `WM_PASTE`.

Comment: Don't use an edit control, use a lable of something and simulate a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set a check in the textbox's `Change` event to compare to clipboard contents. If they match, disallow the change (i.e., set to prior value, default, blank, etc.)

The advantage of this approach is that it is independent of the numerous methods of pasting clipboard content.